# on mousemove call a function

Tags: jquery, random

Looking for some assistance here... The goal is:

On page load, wait for 5 seconds, then from the list of children divs of parent "gridResponsive", select a random child div (one of those titled "grid-item", then perform a function (to fade in a child div within this randomly selected div - e.g. the "hovered" div). Wait 3 seconds, then fade out the child child div (e.g. "hovered"), wait another 5 seconds, then re-start this process - e.g. picking another random child div from the "gridResponsive" group - e.g. another "grid-item".

Any ideas? I can't seem to find a solution that works...

Thanks

See example HTML below:

```
<div class="gridResponsive">
<div class="gridinner">
<div class="grid-sizer" style="width: 1px;"></div>
<div class="grid-item width3"><div class="hovered" style="display: none;"><a title="" href="#"><p>Hover Text</p></a></div><img src="assets/images/home/grid/01.jpg" class="grid-itemImage"></div>
<div class="grid-item width2"><div class="hovered" style="display: none;"><a title="" href="#"><p>Hover Text</p></a></div><img src="assets/images/home/grid/02.jpg" class="grid-itemImage"></div>
<div class="grid-item width1"><div class="hovered" style="display: none;"><a title="" href="#"><p>Hover Text</p></a></div><img src="assets/images/home/grid/03.jpg" class="grid-itemImage"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully sure if I understood you correctly, but please have a look at this solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="gridResponsive">
<div class="gridinner">
<div class="grid-sizer" style="width: 1px;"></div>
<div class="grid-item width3"><div class="hovered" style="display: none;"><p>Hover Text0</p></div>
<div class="grid-item width2"><div class="hovered" style="display: none;"><p>Hover Text1</p></div>
<div class="grid-item width1"><div class="hovered" style="display: none;"><p>Hover Text2</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.setTimeout(doMagic, 5000);
});

function doMagic(){
    var items = $('.grid-item').children('.hovered');
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(items.length * Math.random());
    var randomItem = items[randomIndex];
    $(randomItem).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();

    setTimeout(doMagic, 8000);
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/4o0q4nqw/)

Comment: great :) I am happy it helped!